# How to send email after registration in external script?

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account

I wrote external script to add Customer in magento 1.9

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
include_once '../app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app();
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));  
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
$customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
$customer->loadByEmail($_GET['email']);
if($customer->getId()) {
  $res = array("EX");
  echo json_encode($res, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
} else {send 
    $websiteId = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();
    $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
    $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
    $customer   ->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
                ->setStore($store)
                ->setFirstname($_GET['firstname'])
                ->setLastname($_GET['lastname'])
                ->setEmail($_GET['email'])
                ->setPassword($_GET['password']);
    try{
        $customer->save();
        $customer->setConfirmation(null);
        $customer->save();
        //Make a "login" of new customer
        Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->loginById($customer->getId());
        echo json_encode(array("Oke"), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        Zend_Debug::dump($e->getMessage());
    }
}
?>
```

and was successful in inserting customer data.
How to send email after registering customer with external script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code for registration

```
$customer->sendNewAccountEmail(
            'registered',
            '',
            Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()
        );
```

if confirmation require :

```
$customer->sendNewAccountEmail(
            'confirmation', 
            '', 
            Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()
        );
```